# Keep having this error : JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Tags: python, json

JSON File
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jb3OdoffyA71vYfojxLedZNPDLq9bn7b/view?usp=sharing]

I am trying to read the JSON file in Python, the JSON file is the same as the link above. The code that I wrote looks like this below

```
lst = []
for line in open(json_path,'r'):
    lst.append(json.loads(line))
```

But for some reason, I kept having this error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)` I am wondering did I do something wrong with code or the JSON file has an error in it?

Comment: You can't load a json file line-by-line.  You have to call `json.loads()` on the entire file content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Update

You can strip the break line (`\n`) out before using `json.loads` function (Thanks to @DeepSpace for the comment):

```py
import json
lst = []
for line in open("sample.json",'r'):
  stripped = line.strip("\n")
  if stripped != "":
    lst.append(json.loads(stripped))
lst
```

Also you can use `ast` module too:

```py
import ast
lst = []
for line in open("sample.json",'r'):
  if line.strip("\n") != "":
    lst.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

##### Explanation

`ast.literal_eval` changes a dictionary or list in the shape of a string (such as `"[1,2,3]"`), to an useable dictionary or list in python (such as `[1,2,3]`).

The output of both codes above would be:

```
[{'content': [{'c_id': '002',
    'p_id': 'P02',
    'source': 'internet',
    'type': 'org'},
   {'c_id': '003', 'p_id': 'P03', 'source': 'internet', 'type': 'org'},
   {'c_id': '005', 'p_id': 'K01', 'source': 'news', 'type': 'people'}],
  'doc_id': '7098727',
  'id': 'lni001',
  'pub_date': '20220301',
  'unique_id': '64WP-UI-POLI'},
 {'content': [{'c_id': '002',
    'p_id': 'P02',
    'source': 'internet',
    'type': 'org'},
   {'c_id': '003', 'p_id': 'P03', 'source': 'internet', 'type': 'org'},
   {'c_id': '005', 'p_id': 'K01', 'source': 'news', 'type': 'people'}],
  'doc_id': '7098727',
  'id': 'lni001',
  'pub_date': '20220301',
  'unique_id': '64WP-UI-POLI'},
 {'content': [{'c_id': '002',
    'p_id': 'P02',
    'source': 'internet',
    'type': 'org'},
   {'c_id': '003', 'p_id': 'P03', 'source': 'internet', 'type': 'org'},
   {'c_id': '005', 'p_id': 'K01', 'source': 'news', 'type': 'people'}],
  'doc_id': '7098727',
  'id': 'lni001',
  'pub_date': '20220301',
  'unique_id': '64WP-UI-POLI'},
 {'content': [{'c_id': '012',
    'p_id': 'K21',
    'source': 'internet',
    'type': 'location'},
   {'c_id': '034', 'p_id': 'P17', 'source': 'news', 'type': 'people'},
   {'c_id': '098', 'p_id': 'K54', 'source': 'news', 'type': 'people'}],
  'doc_id': '7097889',
  'id': 'lni002',
  'pub_date': '20220301',
  'unique_id': '64WP-UI-CFGT'},
 {'content': [{'c_id': '012',
    'p_id': 'K21',
    'source': 'internet',
    'type': 'location'},
   {'c_id': '034', 'p_id': 'P17', 'source': 'news', 'type': 'people'},
   {'c_id': '098', 'p_id': 'K54', 'source': 'news', 'type': 'people'}],
  'doc_id': '7097889',
  'id': 'lni002',
  'pub_date': '20220301',
  'unique_id': '64WP-UI-CFGT'}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I am curious how can you tell/check each line of the json is a dict?

Comment: @CodingStark Glad to help. Because they are in the shape of a dictionary. Dictionaries start with `{` and end with `}`. Of course, there would be much more elements that define a dictionary.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much
Also, I tried the ```line.strip("\n")``` approach but it gave me error ```JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)```

Comment: @CodingStark Oh, it's kinda weird! Because I have downloaded the `sample.json` file and tried both mentioned scripts, and they all work fine! Not sure why you are getting this error.

Comment: @CodingStark Oh, your sample JSON file has a few break lines without having any other characters. I have edited the answer as per your comment, hopefully, it fits to your question now.